# Programmatically select an option - Materialize css

Tags: javascript, css, materialize

How can I programmatically select an option from select in Materialize css?
I tried to append the value for select with its first option.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

```js
$('select').material_select();
$('#select_1').val($('#select_1 option:first').val());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css">


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="input-field col s12">
    <select id="select_1" name="select_1">
      <option disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
      <option>Option 1</option>
      <option>Option 2</option>
      <option>Option 3</option>
      <option>Option 4</option>
      <option>Option 5</option>
      <option>Option 6</option>
    </select>
    <label for="select_1">Select 1</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to call the `material_select()` on it again.

Keep in mind though that the `:first` you use to select the `option` targets the `<option disabled selected>Choose your option</option>` one.

```js
$(function(){
  $('select').material_select();
 
  var select = $('#select_1');
  
  select.find('option:eq(2)').prop('selected', true);
  select.material_select();
 
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="input-field col s12">
    <select id="select_1" name="select_1">
      <option disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
      <option>Option 1</option>
      <option>Option 2</option>
      <option>Option 3</option>
      <option>Option 4</option>
      <option>Option 5</option>
      <option>Option 6</option>
    </select>
    <label for="select_1">Select 1</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: if that *other* function is also bound with jquery on the `change` event then yes, you can call `select.trigger('change')`